# Distinguish NaN value and string 'NaN' in Pandas value_counts function

Tags: python, pandas, nan, nonetype

in python I have a list of `[None, None, 'NaN', 'NaN', None]`

When i apply value_counts function on the pandas series of this list, the result is:

```
NaN 3
NaN 2
```

which I cannot distinguish which is which.

Is there another method I can distinguish the string `'NaN'` literally and value `NaN`?

Comment: do you mean visually? where will you visualize it? shell? notebook? file?

Answer (score 2):

How you visualize the output and what you exactly expect is unclear, but you could add a suffix to the string NaN:

```
(pd.Series([None, None, 'NaN', 'NaN', None])
   .add(' (str)')
   .value_counts(dropna=False)
)
```

output:

```
NaN          3
NaN (str)    2
dtype: int64
```

Or `fillna` with a custom string (which makes it work in case you have other types):

```
(pd.Series([None, None, 'NaN', 'NaN', None])
   .fillna('literal NA')
   .value_counts(dropna=False)
)
```

output:

```
literal NA    3
NaN           2
dtype: int64
```